# Is there a way to have the editor reload the latest version in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to always have the latest version of a document updated in an editor. Is there a way to keep the document up to date or refresh it with the latest version without manually closing it and reopening it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078077/visual-studio-code-auto-refresh-file-changes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **depending on the editor**. [*Notepad++*](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), for example, has the setting *File Status Auto-Detection*, giving the user a choice of ignoring changes to any opened file (there may be multiple, since it has a tabbed interface), of being notified of the change, of updating silently, and even scrolling directly to the last line after the update.

[image: Notepad++ File Change Detection]

Other editors or word processors such as LibreOffice *Writer* use [pessimistic transaction control, i.e. file locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129329/optimistic-vs-pessimistic-locking), to prevent modification while the file is open for editing. [LibreOffice *does* have a [Collaboration](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Collaboration) option,  but documents must be merged after editing.]